# Why does Firefox sometimes generate "console not defined" error?

Tags: javascript

Sometimes Firefox generates console not defined error when console.debug() is used. Is this some kind of timing issue with load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Firebug is not present, the `console` object will be `undefined`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061339/ignore-firebug-console-when-not-installed) are some workaround suggestions.

I have no idea what led to this design decision.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell you why, but `window.console.debug()` should always work(assuming there is a console-object in global scope). I've also noticed this behaviour the last time, since that I allways use `window.console` instead of `console`.