# Log to Safari JavaScript Console

Tags: javascript, debugging, safari, console, webkit

Is there any way to log to Safari's JavaScript console when running with the built-in JavaScript debugger?  I've read the [Firefox JavaScript logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783661/log-to-firefox-error-console-from-javascript) question and hoping that there is a simple ("native") way to do it in WebKit/Safari.

Thanks

Comment: console.log() is not working for you on Safari?

Comment: @sean hogan: Apparently it does. Originally I thought it requires some sort of a plugin to be installed like Firefox does.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the same `console` object described in that question. The messages will show up in the console tab.

```
console.log("hello console");
```

`console.log` will work "natively" in Firefox (with Firebug), IE8+, and WebKit browsers (including Safari).

Answer (score 28):

Make sure you have "**All**" selected in the top right corner of the dev tools.

[image: The top right section of the Safari dev tools]
If it's set to "Error" then your Safari will only show [`console.error()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/error).

Comment: Currently dealing with this. Is there any way to change the setting to show `All` by default. When I close the browser window and start a new session it reverts back to just `Errors` view and I'm wondering where the hell all of my debug console messages went. SUPER FRUSTRATING.

Comment: @MarkTomlin no clue. Try looking for a setting from the command line https://pawelgrzybek.com/change-macos-user-preferences-via-command-line/

Answer (score 24):

It works just the same in Safari as it does in Chrome and Firefox. By default the developer tools is not turned on, so make sure you go to `Preferences -> Advanced -> Show Develop Menu in Menu Bar`. Then you can pull up the console with Command+Option+C. (That shortcut obviously assumes Mac, not sure the PC shortcut, but it's in the dropdown as well)

Comment: The PC shortcut is Ctrl+Alt+C

Comment: And make sure All is selected on the Console output tab. Errors is selected by default.