# TypeError: Illegal Invocation on console.log.apply

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

If you run this in the chrome console:

```
console.log.apply(null, [array])
```

Chrome gives you back an error:

```
// TypeError: Illegal Invocation
```

Why? *(Tested on Chrome 15 via OSX)*

Answer (score 182, accepted):

It may not work in cases when execution context changed from console to any other object:

> This is expected because console.info expects its "this" reference to
>   be console, not window.
>
> ```
> console.info("stuff")
> stuff
> undefined
> console.info.call(this, "stuff")
> TypeError: Illegal invocation
> console.info.call(console, "stuff")
> stuff
> undefined
> ```
>
> This behavior is expected.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=48662

Comment: If you need to use as a function, you can use console.info.bind(console)

Comment: so can you use `console.info.call(console, "stuff")` in all browsers that support ES5?

Comment: Same goes for apply: `console.info.apply(console, arguments)`

Comment: Same argument applies to other functions such as console.log() and document.writeln(). So, always provide the correct execution context if using call() or apply(). Alternately, use bind() as @JohnWilliams has pointed out.

Comment: This is still applicable to IE11/Edge when the DevTools F12 are not open.