# jQuery ajax TypeError: illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm working on an Ajax project. Everything on my page works, including this section:

```
var data =  {
    doc:     "sample", 
    action:  "updatemsg", 
    dbid:    97, 
    message: "text"
};

$.ajax({
    url:     ANNOTATION_ENDPOINT,
    data:    data,
    success: console.log,
    error:   console.log
});
```

However, on every request, it throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation    jquery.js:974
    fire                                  jquery.js:974
    self.fireWith                         jquery.js:1084
    done                                  jquery.js:7803
    callback                              jquery.js:8518
```

and the `console.log` calls are never made. `ANNOTATION_ENDPOINT` is a valid URL; my other functions use it with no problem.

I've broken down the problem to this small section but I'm baffled here. Any insight?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159233/typeerror-illegal-invocation-on-console-log-apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the log function expects its context to be the console object not an jqXHR so try

```
$.ajax({
    url:     ANNOTATION_ENDPOINT,
    data:    data,
    success: console.log.bind(console),
    error:   console.log.bind(console)
});
```

Comment: Thank you! So it turns out my method of debugging is flawed.