# Functional Programming: Printing to JS console in Chrome

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm implementing functional programming from Eloquent Javascript to my JS console in Google Chrome. There's a function that loops through each element in an array and performs the given action in the initial parameter to said element.

```
function forEach(array, action) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
       action(array[i]);
}   

forEach(["Wampeter", "Foma", "Granfalloon"], console.log);
```

I am expecting the console to print out each item in my array, but I get this in red:

```
TypeError: 'Illegal Invocation'
```

Is there a way I can print this on my js console or should I use something else to compile the code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [typeerror illegal invocation on console.log.apply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159233/typeerror-illegal-invocation-on-console-log-apply)

Comment: +1 for a Vonnegut fan.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass it to `forEach`, the function is losing the reference to its `this` value (the `console` object). The following should work:

```
function forEach(array, action) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
       action(array[i]);
}   

forEach(["Wampeter", "Foma", "Granfalloon"], console.log.bind(console));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/th2A5/

For browsers that don't support `bind`, you can use the shim available on the [MDN documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Is there a browser that doesn't support `bind` but `console.log`?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you...

```
function forEach(array, action) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
       action(array[i]);
}   

forEach(["Wampeter", "Foma", "Granfalloon"], function(x) {console.log(x);});
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Chrome's console.log doesn't seem to work as a callback.

This code seems to work, though: `for (item in ["a","b","c"]) console.log(item);` and `a = ["a","b","c"]; for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) console.log(a[i]);`

I'd not suggest using the JS console anyway, but that's up to you.

Comment: Oh, and you could just do `["Wampeter", "Foma", "Granfalloon"].forEach(somefunction);` or etc by the way.

Comment: is there another way I can compile my code without using `alert(val)`?

Comment: @DimeCadmium: That doesn't work for `somefunction == console.log` as well. You'd need to use `["Wampeter", "Foma", "Granfalloon"].forEach(console.log, console)`

Comment: Ahh, THAT'S why. Right, my point wasn't that it is a solution to this problem, there's just no need to make your own forEach(array, callback) when you're provided a array.forEach(callback) by JS.