# Illegal invocation when executing passed function

Tags: javascript

I am passing function to other function. It returns `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` when passing native `console.log` function to it. Why's that?

```
var functionToUse = console.log,
    parameterToUse = 'Hello World!';

function execute(logic, parameter) {
    if (parameter) {
         logic(parameter);   
    } else if (!parameter) {
         logic();   
    }
}

execute(function () { alert(1) }, false); // works fine
execute(functionToUse, parameterToUse); // Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [typeerror illegal invocation on console.log.apply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159233/typeerror-illegal-invocation-on-console-log-apply)

Comment: So it's just console behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the `log` function to the `console` object when you pass it around.
Otherwise the `this` value internally will point to `window` and it will result in an illegal invocation.

```
var functionToUse = console.log.bind(console);
```

This would result in an illegal invocation as well:

```
console.log.call(window);
```