# Call console.log with apply

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a logging proxy where each log statement has a prefix.

What I want is to do:

```
customDebug("xxx","yyy");
```

and under the wood it will do:

```
console.debug("prefix","xxx","yyy");
```

I've tried to implement it this way:

```
prefixLogArguments: function(arg) {
    var array = _.toArray(arg);
    array.unshift( this.getPrefix() );
    return array;
},

customDebug: function() {
    var argArray = this.prefixLogArguments(arguments);
    console.debug.apply(undefined, argArray );
},
```

It says `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`  because it seems we can't invoke native code with `apply/call`, even with an undefined context.

Can someone tell me how to achieve this?

I can do `console.debug(argArray);` it's not so bad but it does not produce the same result as it logs an array instead of logging an argument list.

Comment: possible duplicate of [typeerror illegal invocation on console.log.apply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159233/typeerror-illegal-invocation-on-console-log-apply)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should give 'console' as context of apply :

```
var customDebug = function() {
    console.debug.apply(console, arguments);
};
```

See : http://jsfiddle.net/X6Sn9

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
console.debug.apply(console, argArray);
```