# Lodash _.map + console.log prints the iterator

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have stumbled upon this unexpected behavior in javascript

```
'use strict';
var _ = require('lodash');
_.map([1, 2, 3], function(x){console.log(x); });
_.map([1, 2, 3], console.log);
```

the two calls to map are behaving differently.

the first is printing the 1, 2, 3 line by line, whereas the latter call to map prints the iterator that map yields.

is there a more elegant way to write the first call? (without using es6 `=>` operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ary`](https://lodash.com/docs#ary) to limit the number of arguments passed to `console.log`.

```
_.map([1, 2, 3], _.ary(console.log, 1))
```

Comment: is not quite what I had expected - but I am dealing with javascript here so, better get in the habit of not wondering

Comment: Yeah; it's a pitfall of optional/varardic arguments and mapping.

Comment: If you're getting an `Illegal invocation` error, try this: `_.map([1, 2, 3], _.ary(console.log.bind(console), 1))` ([reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8159338/2014893))