# Illegal Invocation, lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm wondering why does the following code gives an `Illegal Invocation` error

```
_.flow( console.log ) ( 123 ) // Illegal Invocation

function log(){ _.each(arguments, function(o) { console.log(o) }); }
_.flow( log ) ( 123 ) // 123
```

Running this on Chrome Version 49.0.2623.112 (64-bit) with lodash v4.13.1

To be sepcific I ran this on the developer tools on Chrome by pressing `Ctr+Shift+J` on [lodash's documentation page](https://lodash.com/docs)

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer, based on feedback.

`console.log` must be called properly -- in other words, it must have the right `this` value when called.  Calling it as a method of `console` is one way, but `bind` can also be used.

Example code (taken from my browser's console)

```
// Give us a test function
function ctest(console) { console("It worked") }
ctest(console.log); // This fails

// Set up a properly bound reference
var clog = console.log.bind(console);
ctest(clog); // This works.
```

**Old Snippet removed**

Comment: Thank's I updated the question. I'm surprised that your snippet is working. Which makes me more intrigued.

Comment: ok I found something while digging around, which accroding to it your snippet should NOT work but clearly it is... what's your secret! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159233/typeerror-illegal-invocation-on-console-log-apply

Comment: I'll bet the difference is -- `console.log` is being over-ridden by the snippet environment and it isn't calling the real browser one. Hmm..didn't think of that. I"ll have to test/explore later on.

Comment: @jkris Updated my answer for you.